# Could not load JavaScript 'content_script.js' for content script

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, manifest

I have a simple `manifest.json`, and for some reason I keep bumping into this error

`Could not load JavaScript 'content_script.js' for content script`

**as soon as I add content_scripts**. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "name": "My Extension",
    "description": "A plain text description",
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://messenger.com/*"],
        "js": ["content_script.js"]
      }
    ],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "options_ui": {
      "chrome_style": true,
      "page": "options.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a mitigation for this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I remember completely, I can tell you that this is working for a project of mine: https://gist.github.com/notflip/fb50e87ce8a670da767d9db805343e06

Comment: My issue was that I had a single content_script object instead of an array of content_script objects

Comment: Glad you got it working! Good luck with your extension

Answer (score 0):

I was just having a similar error, and when loading the unpacked extensions in Chrome, I had to select my SOURCE directory that contains both manifest.json and content_script.js

If I select the overall extension directory I had downloaded from GitHub I got the same error you are getting.